# CSS :focus border transition won't work when a border-bottom is already set

Tags: css, css-transitions, border, transition

I'm styling a text input field and the point is for the border and text to change colour when it's focused.

The problem: When I set the styles for "border-bottom" on the initial state, the transition doesn't work.
I messed around in dev tools a bit and when I remove the initial border-bottom, the transition works fine. But I want to still keep my initial border styles, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

I've had a search and experimented for a couple of days, but nothing really worked or helped. So if someone knows the problem, it'd be greatly appreciated!

```css
.contactInput {
    color: #555;
    padding: 7px 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #555;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.contactInput:focus {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input placeholder="Name" class="contactInput" type="text" name="" id=""/>
  <input placeholder="Email" class="contactInput" type="text" name="" id=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: You should add the HTML part also

Comment: what browser are you testing it in??

Comment: Opera, Chrome, Edge and IE

Comment: Not working yet??

Comment: Not yet, I though maybe another line of css was interfering with it, but i verified that that wasn't the case

Comment: transition is working fine in the example.

Comment: @Bhuwan really? It doesn't even work in the example for me or my colleague

Comment: @Trent What transition you are talking about? the color change or width increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You can use `::placeholder` selector to change input's placeholder color.

```
.contactInput::placeholder {
  color: #555
}
```

And when focused,

```
.contactInput:focus::placeholder {
  color: #000
}
```

**2)** Your border-color animation works. Because you select colors close to each other, you may not notice the color change.

Working snippet below:

```css
.contactInput {
    color: #000; /* text color */
    padding: 7px 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* you can use #FFF shortly */
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 2px solid transparent; /* added this for transparent borders */
    border-bottom-color: #555; /* changed this */
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.contactInput:focus {
    /* remove this color: #000; it is not necessary */
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom-color: #000; /* changed this */
    /* remove this transition: all 0.2s ease-in; */
}

/* normal placeholder color */
.contactInput::placeholder {color:#555;opacity:1}
.contactInput:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#555}
.contactInput::-ms-input-placeholder{color:#555}

/* placeholder color when focused */
.contactInput:focus::placeholder {color:#000;opacity:1}
.contactInput:focus:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#000}
.contactInput:focus::-ms-input-placeholder{color:#000}
```

```html
<form>
  <input placeholder="Name" class="contactInput" type="text" name="" id=""/>
  <input placeholder="Email" class="contactInput" type="text" name="" id=""/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct the border-bottom in focus.

```
.contactInput:focus {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

or you could just change border-color

```
.contactInput:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
}
```

Hope this resolves your problem

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Neither seemed to work though (your first suggestion was the original code, not sure why that wasn't in the example, sorry)

Comment: color change on focus doesn't seem to work with transition but the border-color seems to work, try increasing time and color diffrence to see it working

Comment: Exactly! The differences are just too small to be noticeable, but it works as advertised. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/fa6bz0px/1/) where I exaggerated the color differences and transition time. The only thing that doesn't go smoothly is the font-weight.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's working but you can't see. Because it have to different pixel when start and finish. for example =>

```css
    .contactInput {
        color: #555;
        padding: 7px 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        width:200px;
        font-size: 14px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;
        outline: none;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    }

    .contactInput:focus {
        color: #000;
        font-weight: 600;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
       transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    }
```

```html
    <form>
      <input placeholder="Name" class="contactInput" type="text" name="" id=""/>
      <input placeholder="Email" class="contactInput" type="text" name="" id=""/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

what's the wrong? i think your code is working as right. This way you can see better.

```css
.contactInput {
    color: #555;
    padding: 7px 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #555;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.contactInput:focus {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input placeholder="Name" class="contactInput" type="text" name="" id=""/>
  <input placeholder="Email" class="contactInput" type="text" name="" id=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is that the transition isn't working when the border-bottom is applied. Any ideas?